# State change on a losing trade

Tags: pine-script

Is there a way in pinescript to record which candle you were stopped out on or lost a trade on? My strategy has 4 states:

1. Searching for a trade
2. In a buy trade
3. In a Sell trade
4. Exit current trade either long or short

I'd like to add another state that tells me I was just stopped out and based on that make different decisions on what to do next with my strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to detect losing trades. Here is the example:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
    
if strategy.netprofit[1] > strategy.netprofit
    label.new(bar_index, low, text = str.format("here is losing trade with size {0} {1}", strategy.netprofit - strategy.netprofit[1], syminfo.currency) )
```